# R has problem to group two columns using group by

Tags: r

I have a quite simple R code, which seems not to be working as expected.

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

file <- fread(file)

file$V1 <- NULL

data <- file %>%
  select(col_a, col_b, col_c) %>%
  group_by(col_a, col_b) %>% 
  mutate(sum = sum(col_c))
```

Some data that could be relevant:

> ```
> Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    148195407 obs. of  3 variables:
>  $ col_a      : int  85888 11111 99999 85888 11111 99999 85888 11111 99999 85888 ...
>  $ col_b    : chr  "aaa" "bbb" "ccc" "aaa" ...
>  $ col_c: int  4352 4352 52896 4352 48960 48960 48960 4352 27539 4352 ...
> ```

**PROBLEM**: It is not grouping the data according to **col_a** and **col_b**

Comment: Could be that you have loaded `plyr` along with `dplyr` resulting in masking of `mutate` from dplyr use `dplyr::mutate(sum = sum(col_c))`

Comment: Also, have you tried `dat.atable` methods as it is a big dataset i.e `file[,  Sum := sum(col_c), .(col_a, col_b)]`

Comment: the second comment sure solved the problem. I didn't know that datatable is more suitable for big datasets.

Comment: Not sure why the `tidyverse` is not working for you.  I was thinking that it is due to masking of function.

Comment: could you please explain to me the function call you are using?  what are the parameters meaning

Comment: Updated the post with some description. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the OP's dataset is already a data.table (`fread` output is a `data.table`), and as it is a large dataset, it may be more efficient to use `data.table` methods

```
library(data.table)
file[, Sum := sum(col_c), by = .(col_a, col_b)]
```

Here, we group by 'col_a', 'col_b', and get the `sum` of 'col_c' in `j` and assign (`:=`) the output to create the 'Sum' column

If we need only a summary output, then instead of assignment,

```
file[, .(Sum = sum(col_c)), by = .(col_a, col_b)]
```

Comment: is it possible to extend this call to two functions? instead of getting only one extra column with sum, also another one with max?

Comment: @CroatiaHR. You can do `.(Sum = sum(col_c), Max = max(col_c)),`